# How do I retrieve post only from the users im following and how to structure the data in real time database? Im using React and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a function where i retrieve all the user ids that I am following, then retrieve all there post and display them on my home feed.

This is my current code in the componentWillMount lifecyle method. But its setup to where I only retrieve post made by the current signed in user (which is not an ideal program). But that was just to get the add post functionality working.
How can i make a function where I retrieve  uid's I am following then get there post. The post info does not include the users info like username, etc etc so i need to make a call to get that data as well. (so the process as you can see is very tedious). Please look at the Json tree I provided so you can understand how my data is structured then you will clearly get what I am saying. Even if i have to restructure the data I am up for that :) These are screen shots from how my data is currently structured in firebase.

PLEASE SEE
This is the link to Json tree.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AouzKt9igmJoi0KEF-qEis9NWppS?e=OrffbS

[THIS IS THE POST CARD ON THE TIMELINE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Dca.jpg)

```js
componentWillMount() {

const previousPostList = this.state.postList

var postRef = app.database().ref('Post').child(this.state.currentUserId).child('post')
var userRef = app.database().ref('Users')

postRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  if (this.state.currentUserId === snap.val().userId) {

    userRef.child(this.state.currentUserId).on('value', data => {
      previousPostList.push({
        id: snap.key,
        userId: snap.val().userId,
        profileImage: data.val().profileImage,
        userName: data.val().userName,
        label: data.val().label,
        text: snap.val().text,
        photo: snap.val().photo,
        video: snap.val().video,
        description: snap.val().description,
        audio: snap.val().audio,
        coverArt: snap.val().coverArt,
        title: snap.val().title,
        artist: snap.val().artist,
        album: snap.val().album,
        mixtape: snap.val().mixtape,
      })
      this.setState({
        postList: previousPostList
      })

    })

  }

})

postRef.on('child_removed', snap => {
  for (var i = 0; i < previousPostList.length; i++) {
    if (previousPostList[i].id === snap.key) {
      previousPostList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  this.setState({
    postList: previousPostList
  })
})
} else {
console.log(this.state.currentUserId)
}

});

}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: i exported the json tree as you said but  im not able to add the file to my question im assuming because of the file type, it only accepts image types

Comment: You can add JSON the same way you add code.

Comment: Thanks!  i just added the Json Tree as a link. it is also editable.